# How to activate the RTD flyout menu?

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm using Sphinx and ReadTheDocs to build the documentation of my project.

I want to display several version to my end user so I built several branch in my admin area :
[image: active version]

But when I'm displaying the doc in my browser (https://sepal-ui.readthedocs.io/en/v_1.1.0/), I cannot click on the flyout menu and change version.

[image: flyout]

Is it normal and how to make it functional ?
I use a `readthedocs.yml` file ([link](https://github.com/12rambau/sepal_ui/blob/a2c0d40338b58273d00dcb921f3f9cec15344a3f/.readthedocs.yml)). Am I missing something ?

Comment: I don't experience the issue you describe. When I click on the menu, I see all the available branches and can select any.

Comment: I just tested it on firefox and it work like a charm. 
i'll move this to the readTheDoc github issue tracker as it seems to be related to Safari

Comment: Maybe it's a security setting in Safari, blocking third-party assets?

Comment: but then why is it working in other online documentation ?

Comment: It might be this specific theme, too. I've never seen it before. It looks nice, though. Please try another theme that comes with Sphinx and see if the problem persists.

Comment: the problem persist if I use the default theme of readTheDoc

Comment: The problem fixed itself with the latest safari version ...

Comment: I just tested with Safari and still have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue.

I could solve it by adding a script (let's call it `flyout.js`) to my `docs/source/_static` directory:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dropdownToggle = $('.sidebar-nav li a.has-dropdown');
    
    dropdownToggle.on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var thisLink = $(this);
      var thisParent = thisLink.parent();
  
      if (thisParent.hasClass('open')) {
        thisParent.removeClass('open');
      } else {
        $('.sidebar-nav li').removeClass('open'); 
        thisParent.addClass('open');
      }
    });

    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
      if (!$(e.target).closest('.sidebar-nav li').length) {
        $('.sidebar-nav li').removeClass('open');
      }
    });
});
```

This scripts gets the flyout drop-down and add open/close features to it.

Once done, you have to add a reference to this script to your `conf.py`, as well as references to its dependencies:

```
html_js_files = [
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js', 
    '_static/flyout.js'
]
```

This worked for me. I have to confess I didn't find this by myself. I was stuck and after a lot of unsuccessful researches I ended up asking ChatGPT. Its answer was not perfect and had inconsistencies, but at least it led me to this (which is, when you think of it, somewhat unbelievable).